# Am I doing Something wrong? I need a little guidance with delimiters. Fairly new to C

Tags: c, parsing

When I try to use parentheses as a delimiter it doesn't seem to work. I'm fairly new to C so go easy on me.

```
char* tempToken = "";
char* delim = { " ,.\n()" };
tempToken = strtok(fileStrings[j], delim);


while (tempToken != NULL)
{
    //copy word by word to the words array
    strcpy(words[i++], tempToken);
    tempToken = strtok(NULL, " ,.\n");

}
```

My expected result would be -
Input:

```
(long-lasting)
```

Output:

```
long-lasting
```

But my actual output is -
Input:

```
(long-lasting)
```

Output:

```
(long-lasting)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. You are not showing any effort... what did you try? Any research?

Comment: Works fine for me. You'll need to post a [mcve] in order for others to see the problem.

Comment: Maybe you meant to use `delim` in the call to `strtok` in the loop as well?

Comment: The code as shown, does not scan nor print anything. Please post a complete and best compilable example.

Comment: @rici That might be, but it's not the reason. The code as shown works for me, too. That is, after being augmented with the missing parts for a [example]. So PLEASE, KenzieBussell, provide full source of the erroneous code!

Comment: @thebusy: if I had an answer, I would have put it in a different box. This is a comment.

Comment: @rici Right, and I don't mean to offend. But we both don't know what the OP likes to accomplish so it can be totally correct how it's written. OTH it can't be the reason why the **first** token comes out wrong. So it's kind of misleading.

Comment: Where does `fileStrings[j]` point to? Is it a modifiable `char[]` or some read only string literal?

Comment: `char* tempToken = "";` Assigning address of a string literal is not necessary as you assign a new value right away. For initialization you could use `NULL` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have changed the delimiter set on the successive calls(from `" ,.\n()"` to `" ,.\n"`), so even if the latter part of the string contains any parentheses, `strtok()` won't consider those as delimiter. Check your delimiter list if it's ok!

ie: (long-lasting)(long-fasting) will be parsed as 1. long-lasting and 2. (long-fasting).